# Как проверить указанные аргументы discord py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я перерыл весь интернет, но не нашел нужного мне ответа.
Простую проверку аргументов я знаю как делать.
Но, как сделать проверку аргументов, когда их очень много и они разного типа, или указан ли id или mention пользователя?
вот код

```
@commands.command()
async def accept(self, ctx, user: discord.Member = None, o = None, date = None, time = None):
    if any(role.id in adm for role in ctx.author.roles):
        ewModule.log(f"{ctx.author.nick or ctx.author.name} использовал команду: accept", 1)
        if user != discord.Member: await ctx.send(f"Пользователь не найден")
    else: ewModule.log(f"{ctx.author.nick or ctx.author.name} не хватило прав использовать: accept", 3)
```

К примеру когда 1 аргумент user не указан, надо что бы в чат писало "пользователь не найден", но заместо этого, получаю ошибку в консоль о том что пользователь не найден.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самым простым для вас и для пользователей решением, будет переход на slash-команды.

`discord-py` - устаревшая библиотека без поддержки таких команд и других новых фишек дискорда, поэтому нужно установить другую библиотеку, аналогичную `discord-py`:

```
pip install py-cord==2.0.0b5
```

В целом, вся структура классов, их свойств и методов в `py-cord` осталась такой же как в `discord-py`, поэтому ничего менять и переписывать не нужно. Поэтому к `py-cord` подойдет документация от `discord-py`, но я все же рекомендую пользоваться **[документацией](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/)** именно от `py-cord`

---

Итак, чтобы сделать функцию не префикс-командой, а слеш-командой, заменяем декоратор `@bot.command()` на `@bot.slash_command()`

В декораторе можно сразу же указать название и описание команды:

```py
@bot.slash_command(name='test', description='Тестовая команда для проверки аргументов')
```

А в качестве типа аргументов указываем параметр `Option()`

```py
from discord.commands import Option
```

`Option()` принимает на вход

`тип параметра`

`описание параметра`

`required`: `обязателен параметр или нет`

`default`: `стандартное значение параметра, если он не был указан`

Последнее имеет смысл указывать только если параметр не обязателен (`required=False`)

В итоге команда выглядит так:

```
@bot.slash_command(name='test', description='Тестовая команда для проверки аргументов')
async def test(
   ctx, 
   user: Option(discord.Member, 'Пользователь', required=True), 
   o: Option(str, 'Описание параметра', required=True),
   date: Option(str, 'Дата', required=False, default=None),
   time: Option(str, 'Время', required=False, default=None)
   ):
```

---

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Параметры теперь можно указывать в разном порядке и если не указать обязательные, то дискорд не пропустит команду:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Полный код:**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.commands import Option

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.slash_command(name='test', description='Тестовая команда для проверки аргументов')
async def test(ctx, user: Option(discord.Member, 'Пользователь', required=True), o: Option(str, 'Описание параметра', required=True), date: Option(str, 'Дата', required=False, default=None), time: Option(str, 'Время', required=False, default=None)):
    pass

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Это решение вполне подходит, спасибо большое!