# Генератор Эмбеда dicrord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def emb(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, *, t1tle, hi, ):
    embed=discord.Embed(title=t1tle, description=hi)
    embed.set_footer(text="")
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Есть вот такой вот код, через чат запрашиваются аргументы, но это не работает.

```
Ignoring exception in command emb:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\artem\PycharmProjects\Bombee\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: emb() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'hi'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\artem\PycharmProjects\Bombee\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\artem\PycharmProjects\Bombee\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\artem\PycharmProjects\Bombee\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: emb() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'hi'
```

Answer (score 0):

При использовании оператора `*` весь остальной текст сообщения будет записан в переменную `title` и аргумент `hi` в этом случае не будет передан в функцию, хотя он является обязательным.

Именно поэтому возникает ошибка о том, что аргумент `hi` не был передан.

Подробнее [**здесь**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82).

---

**Решение:**

Чтобы решить проблему, просто сначала принимайте аргументы, состоящие из одного слова, а уже затем весь остальной текст:

```py
async def emb(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, hi, *, title)
```

---

Либо, если в `hi` тоже нужно принять больше 1 слова, можно попросить пользователя указать такие аргументы с новой строки.

Тогда вы сможете получить аргументы так:

```py
async def emb(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, *, title_and_hi):
    title, hi = title_and_hi.split('\n')
    print(f'title: {title}')
    print(f'hi: {hi}')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вывод:**

```py
title: значение аргумента title
hi: значение аргумента hi
```

---

Или, 3 вариант - slash-команды, в которых аргументы можно передавать не по порядку. Пример [**здесь**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1405663/373173).