# Слеша команда в discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

Я испробовал кучу методов, для создания слеш команды, но никакой не работал, в чем проблема?

```
import discord
import config
from discord import app_command
from discord import app_command
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = config.settings['prefix'],intents=intents)
@app_commands.command(name="command-1")
async def top(mes):
    await mes.send('Hi!')
bot.run(config.settings['token'])
```

Comment: Вот пример реализации слеш-команды: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1405663/373173

Comment: @denisnumb в строке from discord.commands import Option , сразу выдает ошибку, не определяет Option

Comment: Библиотеку `discord-py` нужно снести и установить `py-cord`, как указано в ответе по ссылке

Comment: @denisnumb я удалил discord py и установил через терминал пайчарм пайкорд, как показано в ответе.

Comment: Я пайчармом не пользуюсь, слышал там какой-то баг есть с библиотеками python. Попробуйте запустить отдельным скриптом